# 'find', 'chattr', the command on the terminal works fine. But the command in crontab is not good

Tags: cron

I am using the 'a' directory as the 'samba' directory,

I made it freely, not to be deleted 10 minutes after it was made.

'find', 'chattr', the command on the terminal works fine

```
~$ sudo find /home/a/* -type f -mmin +10 -exec  chattr +i {} \;
```

But the command in crontab is not good

```
* * * * * find /home/a/* -type f -mmin +10 -exec  chattr +i {} \;
```

What is the cause?

Comment: How did you add that cronjob? Did you just `crontab -e` or `sudo crontab -e`? I'm asking because your working command is prefixed by `sudo` while the cronjob is not.

Comment: I know that crontab runs with root privileges. Is there a regular user crontab?

Comment: No, crontab entries added via `crontab -e` run as the user who issued that command. If you want to run it as root, then you must add the job to root's crontab (via `sudo crontab -e`), not to yours (`crontab -e`). Every user has his/her own crontab and the jobs defined therein are run as _that_ user, not as root. Else the whole security and permission concept would not make sense if everyone could install cronjobs that run with root privileges.

Comment: It works because I have root privileges.
'sudo crontab -e' works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Cron doesn't import any environment variables, so to get that to work properly, you need a `PATH=path1:path2:…` line at the top of your crontab file so that `find` and `chattr` can be located. Something like:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
* * * * * find /home/a/* -type f -mmin +10 -exec  chattr +i {} \;
```

Alternatively, you can use full paths for commands:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/find /home/a/* -type f -mmin +10 -exec /usr/bin/chattr +i {} \;
```

Comment: It does not work on my computer.  My computer specs 'Linux version 4.15.0-36-generic '

Comment: Cron's default environment should include `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin` AFAIK